# Деление двоичных чисел с получением дробного ответа

Tags: алгоритм, типы-данных, системы-счисления

Можно ли поделить два двоичных числа получив двоичный код ответа в виде дробного числа? Допустим у меня дробь `5/16`, это `00101/10000`, ответ получается `0.0101`. Как такое можно реализовать? В знаменателе будут степени *2*, поэтому проблем с периодичностью быть не должно(насколько я понимаю). Можно было бы перевести в десятичную, посчитать и вернуть, но в таком случае при больших значениях я потеряю часть знаков после запятой, да и у вещественных типов есть погрешность.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в знаменателе **степень двойки** 2<sup>n</sup>, то просто в двоичной записи сместите точку на n знаков влево...

5 - это 101, делить на 16 - 2 0.0101
12 - это 1100, делить на 128 - 0.0001100